# Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch

Всем привет. ПОСТ запрос к АПИ с помощью Фетч

```
getResource = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://fan-foto-ml753mfuuq-uc.a.run.app/api/v1/login/access-token', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS'
            // 'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN',

        },
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        body: 'grant_type=&username=charles%40mavencodom&password=test&scope=&client_id=&client_secret='
    });
    // if (!res.ok) {
    //     throw new Error(`Not Fetch, received ${res.status}`)
    // }
    const body = await res.json();
    return body;
};
```

Получаю **Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input**
Eсли раскометировать **if**, то получаю **Not Fetch, received 0**
Статус запроса при этом 200, но ответа нет.
ПОдскажите, пожалуйста что не так.

Comment: А что возвращает то запрос? Посмотрите во вкладке Network в DevTools.

Comment: В Network - response -  Failed to load response data

Comment: Ну видимо проблема в бэкэнде?